# RGB to HSI conversion

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

There is an image of size 3x3 pixel. Now i need to convert those RGB values of only those pixels whose channel numbers are not exactly the same to their corresponding HSI values. What is this question asking?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KvZW.png)